# Сжатие текстовых данных

Tags: c#, .net, сжатие, lzw

Для сжатия данных использую алгоритм LZW. Проблема в том что я не понимаю куда сохранять список ключей словаря, по которым я далее буду выстраивать новый словарь и декодировать. Пытался запихнуть в .txt с помощью StreamWriter, но объем файла толком то и не уменьшается. Вопросы:

1. Куда стоит записывать результат
2. Как после записи открыть этот файл и декодировать обратно

   ```
   class LZW
   {

        Dictionary<string, ushort> _lzwCode;
        Dictionary<string, ushort> _lzwDecode;
        public List<ushort> result = new List<ushort>();
        public LZW()
        {
            _lzwCode = new Dictionary<string, ushort>();
            _lzwDecode = new Dictionary<string, ushort>();
        }

        public void Coding(string text){

            ushort index = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
                if (!_lzwCode.ContainsKey(text[i].ToString())){
                    _lzwCode.Add(text[i].ToString(), (ushort)index);
                    _lzwDecode.Add(text[i].ToString(), (ushort)index);
                    index++;
                }

            string prefix = String.Empty, suffix = String.Empty;

            foreach (var item in text){
                suffix = prefix + item;

                if (_lzwCode.ContainsKey(suffix))
                    prefix = suffix;

                else{
                    _lzwCode.Add(suffix, index++);
                    var x = _lzwCode[prefix];

                    result.Add(_lzwCode[prefix]);
                    prefix = item.ToString();
                }
            }

            if (prefix.Length > 0)
                result.Add(_lzwCode[prefix]);


        }

        public string Decode(string text)
        {


            string resultText = String.Empty;

            int ind = 0;
            ushort index = (ushort)_lzwDecode.Count;
            string past = string.Empty;
            string curr = string.Empty;

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                curr = text[ind].ToString();
                if (_lzwDecode.ContainsValue(item))
                {
                    resultText += _lzwDecode.ElementAt(item).Key;

                    if (!_lzwDecode.ContainsKey(past + curr))
                        _lzwDecode.Add(past + curr, index++);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!_lzwDecode.ContainsKey(past + curr))
                        _lzwDecode.Add(past + curr, index++);
                }
                past = _lzwDecode.ElementAt(item).Key; 
                ind += past.Length;
            }

            return resultText;
        }

    }
   ```

result - конечный список индексов

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = String.Empty;

        using (StreamReader streamReader
            = new StreamReader(@"путь к файлу\text.txt"))
            text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        var lzw = new LZW();
        lzw.Coding(text);

        using(StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"путь к файлу\res.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var item in lzw.result)
                streamWriter.Write(item + " ");
        }

    }
```

[image: Результаты. Слева файл с ключами]

Comment: Как проверяете реализацию, что в аргумент передается, что ожидается в итоге, в чем задача? Ваш метод `void` ничего не возвращает.

Comment: после исполнения алгоритма result передается дальше для внесения его в файл, я просто не весь код скопировал, а только алгоритм

Comment: с этим обрубком кода ничего не сделать, так как 1) непонятно, как его тестировать 2) непонятен ожидаемый результат 3) чтобы протестировать метод кодирования, нужен работающий метод декодирования, иначе не проверить.

Comment: Добавил весь класс, после вызова метода Coding, я получаю собственно result, а после его записывают в файл. Декодирование тоже тестил, вроде работает без нареканий

Comment: Как проверяете? Что кодируете?

Comment: Загружал текст объемом 110тыс симв, а после записывал результат в .bit файл

Comment: Так что вам нужно? Просто `List<ushort>` сохранить в файл чтоли?

Comment: Дело в том что я сохранил, но объем файла по сравнению с обычным текстом не сильно так меняется, мне нужно сжимать хотя бы на половину этот файл

Comment: А как вы сохранили? Вы покажете проблемный код, или дальше вокруг да около ходить будем?

Comment: Всю информацию добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь записать числа как текст. Пишите числа как числа.

Записать

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"путь к файлу\res.lzw"))
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
{
    foreach (var item in lzw.result)
        bw.Write(item);
}
```

Прочитать

```
List<ushort> loaded = new List<ushort>();
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"путь к файлу\res.lzw"))
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
{
    int length = (int)br.BaseStream.Length / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        loaded.Add(br.ReadUInt16());
}
```

Comment: Сработало, спасибо большое, и у меня один вопрос к решению: когда мы созданием файл с расширением lzw, то получается в него запись идет как числа, я верно понял? И почему Вы br.BaseStream.Length делите на 2

Comment: @Tura расширение не влияет на содержимое файла, да, пишу как числа, делю потому что длина `ushort` 2 байта.

Comment: @Tura `br.BaseStream` можно заменить просто на `fs`. Это одно и то же.

Comment: Ага, насколько я понял при использовании данного потока длину мы считаем количеством байтов, а при считывании срабатывает метод ReadUInt16(), который нам сразу возвращает `ushort`

Comment: @Tura ` вот этот символ по краям, чтобы кусочек кода выделить.

Comment: спасибо, так гораздо лучше